# batch files to download only today file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

i am having 'n' of files in folder with different date, but i want to download only today's file.please help me out in this.there is no date format in file name, based on the modification date only i have to download the file through FTP,

please help me out.

Thanks

Selva

Comment: This is likely quite complicated, date parsing in batch is not pretty :) check this link which might help you out http://stackoverflow.com/q/7412623/799586

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `forfiles` command to get the files which are only one day older or are modified  only today.

for eg. if you want to download some files from a folder(source_folder) which are modified today then to your folder(destination_folder):

```
forfiles /P %path to source_folder%  /M *.txt  /D -0 /C "cmd copy @fname %path_of_destination_folder% "
```