# download file from FTP and store those files in daily dated folder

Tags: ftp

I am trying to download file from FTP   and store those files in daily dated folder, however files must be copied into dated folder as shown below
C:\backup\created daily folder\files  download from ftp

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=" %%a in ('date /T') do set datestr=%%a
set time=%TIME:~0,2%" "%TIME:~3,2%
mkdir C:\%date:/=%" "%time%\
FTP
open 127.0.0.1
admin
123
cd /ftpsrv
lcd C:\%date:/=%" "%time%\
Prompt
mget *.*
quit
```

Comment: Is that supposed to be a batch file? You are a long way from your goal. Start by writing a batch file that downloads a file with a fixed name. And only then try the dynamic name.

Comment: See also [Windows batch script to download yesterday files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7412623/850848). I suggest you try (my) WinSCP. Your task will be way easier. See my answer to that question.